# How to get parent PID of a given process in GNU/Linux from command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, process, pid

Resolved before asked: `cat /proc/1111/status | grep PPid`

Comment: faster: `grep PPid status |cut -f2` like in `time(for((i=0;i<1000;i++));do grep PPid status |cut -f2 >/dev/null;done)`; wonder if there is something even faster?

Comment: @AquariusPower Since you ask, fgrep is faster than grep. `fgrep PPid status |cut -f2`

Comment: sed is way faster than grep and cut: `sed -rn '/PPid/ s/^.*:\s+// p' < status`

Comment: `pid=3773234; while true; do pid=$(awk '/^PPid:/{print $NF}' /proc/$pid/status);printf "$pid\n"; if [ $pid -eq 1 ];then break;fi;done|tac`

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Command line:

```
ps -o ppid= -p 1111
```

Function:

```
ppid () { ps -p ${1:-$$} -o ppid=; }
```

Alias (a function is [preferable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases)):

```
alias ppid='ps -o ppid= -p'
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
pid=$1
if [ -z $pid ]
then
    read -p "PID: " pid
fi
ps -p ${pid:-$$} -o ppid=
```

If no PID is supplied to the function or the script, they default to show the PPID of the current process.

To use the alias, a PID must be supplied.

Comment: The `=` sign is not necessary, at least on OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: @jtbandes: The equal sign as used here suppresses the output of the header line ([Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) and [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/ps.1.html)).

Comment: prefer _alias_ if you want any shell auto-complete to still work

Comment: Auto-completion of function names works just fine for me.

Answer (score 20):

To print parent ids (`PPID`) of all the processes, use this command:

```
ps j
```

For the single process, just pass the PID, like: `ps j 1234`.

To extract only the value, filter output by `awk`, like:

```
ps j | awk 'NR>1 {print $3}' # BSD ps
ps j | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' # GNU ps
```

---

To list PIDs of all parents, use `pstree` (install it if you don't have it):

```
$ pstree -sg 1234
systemd(1)───sshd(1036)───bash(2383)───pstree(3007)
```

---

To get parent PID of the current process, use `echo $$`.

Comment: `pstree` is the nicest one I've seen here.

Comment: `ps j` is great because it's available on many distros and is easily composable

Answer (score 15):

This is one of those things I learn, forget, relearn, repeat. But it's useful. The pstree command's ‘s’ flag shows a tree with a leaf at N:

```
pstree -sA $(pgrep badblocks)
systemd---sudo---mkfs.ext4---badblocks
```

Comment: What about `ps f`?

Comment: @Alex78191 why do you ask? What about it? It does something completely different to what the question asked.

Answer (score 14):

Parent pid is in shell variable PPID, so

```
echo $PPID
```

Comment: Yes, but 1. I want parent pid of other process, 2. I want to be able to traverse all ancestors to init.

Comment: On the other hand, using `$PPID` did just solve the problem I had which Google suggested this page as an answer to.

Answer (score 10):

Read /proc/$PID/status. Can be easily scripted:

```
#!/bin/sh
P=$1
if [ -z "$P" ]; then
    read P
fi
cat /proc/"$P"/status | grep PPid: | grep -o "[0-9]*"
```

Comment: `grep '^PPid:' /proc/$1/status | grep -o '[0-9]*'` is all you need. (It is _very uncommon_ for Unix tools to do the `if [ -z ]; then read` thing.)

Comment: @grawity It helps do do things like `echo $$ | ppid | ppid | ppid`

Comment: UUOC useless use of cat

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez, My hands are not used to type `< /some/file grep | grep | ...`.

Comment: What about `grep /some/file`

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me on an embedded system that only had one flag for ps (-w for wide output) so all of the answers using ps did not work for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

On Linux:

```
ps hoppid $thatprocess
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ ps -p $(ps -p $(echo $$) -o ppid=) -o comm=
    tmux
```

A little bit more complex example that checks the command of a parent that started current process
Change comm= to cmd= to see full command

Comment: Useless use of _echo_? ;)

Comment: It is actually required on some terminals. To be honest I don't remember exactly but it actually solved a problem. :D

Answer (score 2):

Run `top` with whatever options you want, like `-u username and -p PID`.

And while `top` is working press <kbd>f</kbd>, it shows a list of options you want to display in `top` output, and the displayed parameters will be shown in CAPITAL letters and the parameters which or not displaying will be shown in small letters.

So by entering the letter before the parameter you can enable or disable it. For parent process ID you have to enter <kbd>b</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it'll display the PPID in top output.

Comment: It is to be used non-interactively. I already know that in `htop` you can configure `PPID` column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick solution that should also work:

```
ps $$
```

Comment: That doesn't give the parent PID which is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

## all parent processes of a pid

I came here when I was trying to find "all parent processes of a pid". I ended up making my own recursive function to do it.

### [pid_lineage.sh](https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/b4cb78201ae39745398824a071bfa4d4)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -eu

main(){
  ps --pid ${1:-$$} --no-headers --format pid,ppid,args | \
    (
      read pid ppid args
      echo -e "$pid\t$args"
      [[ $pid -gt 1 ]] && main $ppid
    )
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: @John-Karahalis I appreciate your edit. It was rejected by 2 other reviewers, but I agree and usually use long options to save readers time having to look up the meaning of cryptic flags. Thanks!